# Formik - Select first option in dropdown list when component gets loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have the following code which has a dropdown list with few values.

I want that when the component gets loaded, it selects the first option and let me submit right after.

I tried with the line below but no luck:

```
formik.setFieldValue(name, value);
```

Here you have the code:

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import { get } from 'lodash-es';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const DropdownListInput = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const firstOptionValue = get(props.children, '[0].props.value', '');
    console.log({
      name: props.field.name,
      value: props.value,
      firstOptionValue,
    });
    if (props.value === '' && firstOptionValue !== '') {
      props.formik.setValues({
        [props.field.name]: firstOptionValue,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <select
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e.target.value)}
    >
      {props.children.map(({ props: { value, children: text } }, index) => (
        <option value={value} key={index}>
          {text}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .required('Email is required.')
          .email('Email is invalid.'),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
      enableReinitialize
      validateOnMount
    >
      {(formik) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <div>
              <Field
                component={DropdownListInput}
                formik={formik}
                name="email"
                value={formik.values.email}
                handleChange={(value) => {
                  console.log(value);
                  formik.setFieldValue('email', value);
                }}
              >
                <option value="bill.gates@microsoft.com">Bill Bates</option>
                <option value="steve.jobs@apple.com">Steve Jobs</option>
                <option value="elon.musk@tesla.com">Elon Musk</option>
              </Field>
              <ErrorMessage name="email">
                {(error) => <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>{error}</div>}
              </ErrorMessage>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!formik.isValid} />
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Here you have the Stackblitz you can play with:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-yup-example-uhdg-dt6cgk?file=Registration.js

Is there any way to select the first option automatically when the component gets loaded?

**Requirements:**

- I need the Submit button to be enabled automatically.
- Using `initialValues` is not an option for me because the dropdown is in the middle of a more complex context then it is the same dropdown who has to trigger the setting of that value.

If you want you can post your forked Stackblitz.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the initial value as the default value. Since that would be selected by default, the initial value can reflect the same, and be changed on change.

```
initialValues={{
    email: 'bill.gates@microsoft.com',
  }}
```

Comment: using `initialValues` is not an option for me because the dropdown is in the middle of a more complex context then it is the same dropdown who has to trigger the setting of that value.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem with the solution is?

Comment: I need the the `DropdownListInput` from inside of itself calls the function: `handleChange()` and notifies `formik` that the first option was selected and the submit button gets enabled.

Comment: Well if you want default selected there is no "valid" way to have it call onChange since it's not gonna change, you can always use useEffect to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is very straightforward where you always want to have a selected option in your dropdown, defaulting to the first one. To do that you have to set `select` attribute of  tag just for first one. It's a pure HTML thing.

you can find the reference here:

```
 <option value="bill.gates@microsoft.com" select>
   Bill Bates
 </option>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-yup-example-uhdg-bgzdh7?file=Registration.js

Another scenario would be you want to preserve the user selection on rerenders, to do that you can rely on setting up `initialValues` to what user has selected.

In that way, if any selection is there reflect that or else default to the very first item of the dropdown.

Comment: on the example you provided the Submit button is not enabled (I need that) because the Formik form doesn't have that value set. In the other hand, using `initialValues` is not an option for me because the dropdown is in the middle of a more complex context then it is the same dropdown who has to trigger the setting of that value.